# Security of former President of USA in "Welcome to Mooseport"?

Tags: plot-explanation, welcome-to-mooseport

Why does the former President of the United States of America have an abundance of security with him at all times?

After all, he is only the former president and not the current president.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under U.S. law, former presidents and their families are afforded some protection even after they leave office.

From: [United States Secret Service: Protection](http://www.secretservice.gov/protection.shtml)

> Former presidents and their spouses for their lifetimes, except when the spouse remarries. In 1997, Congressional legislation became effective limiting Secret Service protection to former presidents for a period of not more than 10 years from the date the former president leaves office